# How can one Docker container call another Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have two Docker containers

1. A Web API
2. A Console Application that calls Web API

Now, on my local web api is local host and Console application has no problem calling the API.However, I have no idea when these two things are Dockerized, how can I possibly make the Url of Dockerized API available to Dockerized Console application?

i don't think i need a Docker Compose because I am passing the Url of API as an argument of the API so its just the matter of making sure that the `Dockerized API's` url is accessible by `Dockerized Console`

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution to this problem?  It seems like it should be possible for a service running on container A to make a web call to container B.  I don't know why the below answer of docker-compose.yml is the accepted solution but it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be solved easily if using compose feature. With compose, you just create one configuration file (`docker-compose.yml`) like this :

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

To make it run, just call `up` like this :

```
docker-compose up
```

This is the best way to run all your stack, so, check this reference :
https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Success!

Comment: So to understand, we want to make a web call from one docker container to a service in another docker container and the above is a solution?  That literally makes no sense.  Need to explain more.

Comment: Need more explanation of how did it work to be a correct answer

Comment: It didn't work for me. Nothing to tell this is the right answer.

Answer (score 18):

The idea is not to pass the url, but the hostname of the other container you want to call.
See [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

This is what replace the [deprecated `--link` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/).

And if your containers are not running on a single Docker server node, [Docker Swarm Mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/) would enable that discoverability across multiple nodes.

Answer (score 12):

This is the best way I have found to connect multiple containers in a local machine / single cluster.

**Given:** data-provider-service, data-consumer-service

- Option 1: Using Network

```
docker network create data-network
docker run --name=data-provider-service --net=data-network -p 8081:8081 data-provider-image
docker run --name=data-consumer-service --net=data-network -p 8080:8080 data-consumer-image
```

Make sure to use URIs like: `http://data-provider-service:8081/` inside your `data-consumer-service`.

- Option 2: Using Docker Compose

You can define both the services in a docker-compose.yml file and use `depends_on` property in `data-provider-service`.
e.g.

```
data-consumer-service:
  depends_on:
    - data-provider-service
```

You can see more details here on my Medium post: https://saggu.medium.com/how-to-connect-nultiple-docker-conatiners-17f7ca72e67f

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `link` option with `docker run`:

Run the API:

```
docker run -d --name api api_image
```

Run the client:

```
docker run --link api busybox ping api
```

You should see that `api` can be resolved by docker.

That said, going with `docker-compose` is still a better option.

Comment: Just a heads up: Container links are now deprecated in favor of user-defined networks per: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: This isn't explained.  From one service I want to make a call like "http://some_network/some_method to another.  How is this a solution?