# Execution between docker container

Tags: docker

I would like to know if it's possible to create a kind of communication between two docker container.

I've two docker containers, one for Firefox and another one for vscode. I'm looking for a solution to be able to open URL link from vscode in my running Firefox container(create a new tab as we have when we are selecting a link).

Don't know if it's possible to do that. Maybe by sharing some specific resource.

Thanks

Comment: Is this what you were looking for ???https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275794/how-can-one-docker-container-call-another-docker-container

Comment: Using the `docker-compose.yaml` file and `depends_on`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the possibility but there are two scenarios:

1. Either you find a way/extension to make vscode call a browser over network
2. Mount the needed files/binaries as a volume from firefox container to vscode container to make it able call the firefox binary locally as usual in order to make it able to open the browser (not tested but might be done somehow) but it might not be able to open in the same session, so give it a try and let me know so i can update the answer.